# Implementing custom bottom tab navigator flutter

Tags: flutter, button, floating-action-button, menubar

I am trying to implement a custom bottom tab navigator by doing step by step from this source: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013. It uses the combination of floating action bottom and BottomAppBar. The problem is.. if I click the floating action button to navigate user to a screen the bottom tab navigator will be lost. Is there a way to keep bottom tab navigator is still exist when user click the floating action button (where the button will navigate to a screen) or is there a way to make custom bottom tab navigator like this without floting action button:[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to use nested navigation. [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav) is a tutorial.